# what's wrong with concatenation in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

For the life of me, I can't understand why adding a concatenated string to the MainScreen is causing the BB simulator to throw an exception. If I run a VERY simple hello program with the following control, all is well:

```
RichTextField rtfHello = new RichTextField("Hello There !!!");        
add(rtfItemDescription);
```

But if I add a concatenated string, the entire app breaks:

```
String MyName = "John Doe";
RichTextField rtfHello = new RichTextField("Hello There !!!" + MyName);        
add(rtfItemDescription);
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why would the simulator throw an exception for the second example?

Comment: what Exception is being thrown?

Comment: Indeed, without the exception detail this is very difficult to answer.

Comment: The "Hello There" + myName causes a run-time string concatention, which would be fine except that your Eclipse is generating real and modern Java code whereas BB5/6/7 requires last-century (literall) Java ME which uses StringBuffer. You have to first ensure that your project build properties are set to Java Compiler -> Source Level 1.3 or 1.4 (search this topic before responding!). This used to be enough, but apparently after a software upgrade to Eclipse in March 2013 this doesn't even solve the problem anymore, for which I am still in search of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it would blow up (but I'm not a blackberry/java developer).  Have you simply tried:

```
String MyName = "John Doe"; 
String HelloString = "Hello There !!!";
RichTextField rtfHello = new RichTextField(HelloString.concat(MyName));         
add(rtfItemDescription);
```

Or simply,

```
String MyName = "John Doe"; 
RichTextField rtfHello = new RichTextField("Hello There!!!".concat(MyName));         
add(rtfItemDescription);
```

Comment: Doesnt work trying to concat `Char`. I believe this is because OS 7.1 and below use Java ME.

Answer (score 2):

For string concatenations in Blackberry try to use StringBuffer class. StringBuffer is faster than String, because it mutable.

Comment: Seems to do the trick :) `StringBuffer str = ""; str.append(Mystring);`

Answer (score 1):

looks as that when i do any string concatenation in my blackberry project (using eclipse), the packaging process cannot find the definition of the class StringBuilder. the project is defaulted to jdk 1.4. StringBuilder wasn't introduced until version 1.5 so attempting to run the code will produce a "no class definition found" error message. So this is my guess as to why i am seeing my errors. – sexitrainer Jan 20 at 15:30

This is because StringBuilder is not a part of J2ME. You won't be able to use it while programming for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String MyName = "John Doe";
    RichTextField rtfHello = new RichTextField("Hello There !!!" + MyName);        
    add(rtfHello);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think problem is with string concatenation.
can provide more information like what exception you are getting.

Comment: it looks as that when i do any string concatenation in my blackberry project (using eclipse), the packaging process cannot find the definition of the class StringBuilder. the project is defaulted to jdk 1.4. StringBuilder wasn't introduced until version 1.5 so attempting to run the code will produce a "no class definition found" error message. So this is my guess as to why i am seeing my errors.